# BottomNavigationBarItem - don't turn blue when clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

My code should allow either one of the two BottomNavigationBarItem "Home" or "Defaults" to be clicked and turned blue. However only the "Home" button remains blue, the other won't turn blue when clicked. The idea is once "Defaults" is clicked it will open a new page, but I don't know the code to implement that yet.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
int currentIndex = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Insulin dosing';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Defaults',
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }

  void setState(Null Function() param0) {}
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  Color _fillColor = Colors.white;

  TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
      TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
  TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR4C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR4C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR4C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR5C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR5C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR5C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR6C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR6C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR6C3controller = TextEditingController();

  String result = "0";
  String result2 = "0";
  String result3 = "0";
  String result4 = "0";
  String result5 = "0";
  String result6 = "0";

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    numR1C1controller.dispose();
    numR1C2controller.dispose();
    numR1C3controller.dispose();
    numR2C1controller.dispose();
    numR2C2controller.dispose();
    numR2C3controller.dispose();
    numR3C1controller.dispose();
    numR3C2controller.dispose();
    numR3C3controller.dispose();
    numR4C1controller.dispose();
    numR4C2controller.dispose();
    numR4C3controller.dispose();
    numR5C1controller.dispose();
    numR5C2controller.dispose();
    numR5C3controller.dispose();
    numR6C1controller.dispose();
    numR6C2controller.dispose();
    numR6C3controller.dispose();
  }

  // MAKE LIST OF MAP TO KEEP TRACK OF EACH BUTTONS
  List<Map> buttons = [
    {"name": "BreakFast", "active": false, "value": 1.0},
    {"name": "Lunch", "active": false, "value": 0.55},
    {"name": "Tea", "active": false, "value": 0.55},
  ];

  // YOU CAN SET VARIABLE TO CURRENT MEAL NAME AND CAN CHECK WHETHER IT'S (breakFast) OR NOT
  String? currentMealType;

  // TOGGLE BUTTON FUNCTION
  toggleButtons(Map obj) {
    for (var i in buttons) {
      if (i['name'] == obj['name']) {
        i['active'] = !i['active'];
        numR2C2controller.text = obj['value'].toString();
        _calculateR2();
      } else {
        i['active'] = false;
      }
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  _calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
          double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
      numR4C2controller.text = numR1C2controller.text;
      numR2C1controller.text = numR1C1controller.text; // <-- add this
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _calculateR3();
        _calculateR2();
      });
      result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
    }

    if (numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) < 5
            ? Colors.red
            : double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) > 9.1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.green;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR2() {
    if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR2C2controller.text) *
            double.parse(numR2C1controller.text);
        numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR3C1controller.text = numR2C3controller.text;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _calculateR3();
        });
        result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR3() {
    if (numR3C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR3C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR3C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR3C2controller.text);
        numR3C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR6C1controller.text = numR3C3controller.text;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _calculateR3();
          _calculateR4();
          _calculateR6();
        });
        result3 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR4() {
    if (numR4C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR4C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR4C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR4C2controller.text);
        numR4C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR5C1controller.text = numR4C3controller.text;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _calculateR5();
        });
        result4 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR5() {
    if (numR5C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR5C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR5C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR5C2controller.text);
        numR5C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR6C2controller.text = numR5C3controller.text;
        result5 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR6() {
    if (numR6C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR6C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR6C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR6C2controller.text);
        numR6C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result6 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text('Please pick a meal'),
          ),

          // HERE IS THE VIEW FOR BUTTONS
          //******************************

          Row(
            children: buttons
                .map(
                  (btn) => Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => toggleButtons(btn),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: btn['active'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300]!)),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(btn['name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: btn['active']
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.black)),
                            Text(btn['value'].toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: btn['active']
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.black))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text('Input Data'),
          ),

          //******************************

          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  controller: numR1C1controller,
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Carbs in Meal',
                      isDense: true,
                      hintText: 'Enter 1st Number',
                      fillColor: _fillColor,
                      filled: false),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR1C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      filled: true,
                      labelText: 'Current B/G Level',
                      isDense: true,
                      hintText: 'Enter 2nd Number',
                      fillColor: _fillColor),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR1C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Excercise Factor',
                    isDense: true,
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text('Calculations'),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, height: 1.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR2C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Carbs in meal',
                    hintText: 'Enter 3rd Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR2C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Meal Ratio',
                    hintText: 'Enter 4th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR2C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 2',
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR3C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Result 2',
                    hintText: 'Enter Fifth Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR3C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Correction Factor',
                    hintText: 'Enter Sixth Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR3C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 3',
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR4(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR4C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Target Level',
                    hintText: 'Enter Seventh Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR4(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR4C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Current B/G Level',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: 'Enter Eighth Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR4(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR4C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 4',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR5(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR5C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Result Difference',
                    hintText: 'Enter 9th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR5(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR5C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Correction Factor',
                    hintText: 'Enter 10th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR5(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR5C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 5',
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR6(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR6C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Result Actual Units',
                    hintText: 'Enter 11th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR6(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR6C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result Difference',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: 'Enter 12th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR6(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR6C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 6',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `StatefulWidget` widget to update ui. And only single MaterialApp is enough, dont use multiple MaterialApp.

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: const MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Insulin dosing';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(appTitle),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Defaults',
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

More about [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Comment: In to ```body:``` of ```Scaffold()``` put currentIndex of List of pages. For example: ```body: pages[currentIndex],```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks and feel free to update. I was focused on BottomNavBar

Comment: Thanks @Yeasin Sheikh and Sulaymon Ne'matov for your replies. I've not been able to test your suggestions yet as something has gone very wrong with my code, but not sure what, but nothing works anymore, will investigate and then reply.